# Install dstat on Solaris

Tags: solaris, installation

I want to install [dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/) on Solaris. I downloaded the tar package. However, I don't seem to have any instructions on how to install that.

Installing it on Ubuntu was very easy, but struggling on Solaris.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[dstat](http://dag.wieers.com/home-made/dstat/) it is designed for Linux only.

Comment: You can enable SNMP and monitor the Solaris server remotely. On the server you can use `sar`, `prstat`. See also: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/tuning_solaris.html